# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Asp.Net : Cannot view image under my domain after uploading

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have installed AWS SDK for .NET, and by using the toolkit for VS2013 I managed to deploy my application with no problem. The ElasticBeanstalk creates the bucket automatically and names it like elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-1-416461029999

The application has a file uploader which saves the user selected file under the bucket above. My problem is I can view the image by the AWS Explorer, but I would like to view the file by a browser under the domain like www.mydomain.com/Images/filename.jpg

The documentation for static sites says the bucket has to have the same name as the domain name, but the Elastic Beanstalk names the bucket automatically and it is not possible to change it after...

I would really appreciate any help, thanks...

Answer (score 1):

1) First of you have to set ACL permission (Public Read,Write) for particular file
  2) you could not use to see image directly Bucket URL. AWS provide "Distribution URL"  for file    display or view. so you can view file using Distribution URL

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I already set the ACL permission, and will look into to the "Distribution URL" part.

Comment: Now the image is displayed by the CloudFront URL like http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/Images/filename.jpg but still can not view it under mydomain. I have added the cnames as setting up the CloudFront for the bucket. My domain is at godaddy and its @ record is pointed to the elastic IP created for EC2 instance. Is this is wrong? The domain does work and runs the application correctly though.

Comment: Great :) You can see image directly distribution URL, Not in your domain

Comment: But in the document (below is the link) does say it is possible to see the image with a custom domain. 
[link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)

Comment: yeah you can do with "CNAMEs" as per link

Comment: I pinged CloudFront URL to get the IP and used it for the @ record at godaddy. Now the image is displayed with my domain, but the application does not work anymore because the @ record is no longer pointed to the elastic IP of the EC2 instance.

Comment: I m very lost between Cloud Front URL, Elastic IP and BeansTalk URL ... When I point www record to Cloud Front URL, it displays the image with my domain no problem, but then it doesn't point to the application anymore ...